# Split Strings into words and joining them with original separators

Tags: python

I'm working now with strings, and sometimes there are some words that are joined by a specific separator, for example:

"Good-vibes"

I'm making a code to do some operations with the two words separately, but after I modify those words, I want to join them again by the same separator. This separator could change, it can be '_', '+', and other kind of non alphabetical characters.

I'm using RegEx. Is there any way in python for me to separate that kind of strings in the words in it, and join it again by the same separator?

Comment: Are you sure you really need that? If it is the case, just do not split the string into words, but search for each word in string and modify it directly. On the other hand, what trandformation do you want to apply on each word ? It is important to know this in order to answer to your question.

Comment: For example. I have a word, like a last name, with a dash line within. parra-martinez, and I want to capitalize both words, and have this output: Parra-Martinez. But when I split words and I make the changes, I don't know how to join them again with the same separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the last comment you made, you said that you already split them and made the changes.

```
string = "parra-martinez"
string = string.split("-") # Replace with whatever separator

# Do your stuff

string = "-".join(string)
```

This should give you the thing you want.

Comment: This will give the thing I want if I was just doing it for one string, but the thing is there is a lot of those strings, and sometimes inside another larger strings that must remain the same. For example: "parra-martinez had an amazing day", and if I do this, it will output: "Parra-Martinez-Had-An-Amazing-Day" and what I want is "Parra-Martínez had an amazing day"

Comment: Thank you, I will

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt string split() and join() methods:

```
txt = "string-to-split"

string_split_by_dash = txt.split('-')

# do something 

string_joined_by_dash = ('-').join(string_split_by_dash)
```

Here 'string_split_by_dash' is a list, which in python is an iterable. It is useful to notice when things in python are iterables as they can be used directly to loop (e.g. for string in string_split_by_dash:), or in special methods such as join() that take iterators as input.